Php GD Persian/Arabic characters singly in Debian server
I had a server with this config:
OS: CentOS Linux 7.9.2009
PHP: 7.0.27
GD: 2.8.3
I have a simple script to convert Persian text to image:
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
imagettftext($img, 20, 0, 25, 25, $text_color, '/home/font/arial.ttf', 'سلام');
imagejpeg($img);

The code worked properly on the server in many years!
I get new server with this config:
OS: Debian Linux 12
PHP: 8.2.7
GD: 2.8.3
But the script hasn't correct result and the chars print separately!

I don't want to use some solution that based on replaced chars (like this), i need a main solution to solve the problem that the script execute like the old CentOS server. Which module/package must be checked/installed?
(I also try apt-get install php-gd php-intl php-mbstring -y)

For solving the problem, we need to compile GD with "Support for complex text: enabled" option.
or use a compiled version of GD with that option.

with thanks to behdad.org that help to address the issue
